# Modify position after transition ends

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to force changing property position to change after certain part of time (after all animations will end). For this I've created sample codepen so you can see what I've already achieved (more-less):

```
transition: width 0.5s ease-in, height 0.5s, position 0s ease 0.6s;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpQdZm

As you can see hovering on the green container triggers transition of inside container grow (from right to left). What I would like to do is to make the container decrease when we remove the hover effect but to keep the position set to absolute while transition still lasts but set position to static after all transitions ends.

The more illustrative example can be see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyVzed

Because of the changing of position from absolute to static when hover is missing, the images are flickering and it looks so ugly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 800px;
}

.container div {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

.container div img {
  width: 200px;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container div img:hover {
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 200;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}

.container:nth-of-type(even) div img:hover {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(even) img:hover {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/pqwPJPgR6qCB2/giphy.gif">
  </div>
  <div>    
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/f0f4/i/2017/182/c/6/pvz_heroes_random_colored_doodle_of_nc_by_crystilialance-dbeqssx.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/answers/177000/177769_1287459785835_400_300.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6BwaeUjaDnM/TZSPiw4YeoI/AAAAAAAAAf4/YlxYyxxu6nE/s400/2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/answers/177000/177769_1287459785835_400_300.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6BwaeUjaDnM/TZSPiw4YeoI/AAAAAAAAAf4/YlxYyxxu6nE/s400/2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/pqwPJPgR6qCB2/giphy.gif">
  </div>
  <div>    
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/f0f4/i/2017/182/c/6/pvz_heroes_random_colored_doodle_of_nc_by_crystilialance-dbeqssx.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I can set div to fixed height but the problem is I want images to be scaled by its width.

Comment: `position` is not an animatable property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties so it won't work using it in a `transition`

Comment: This I've also noticed, that's why I'm looking for alternative. What can I do to delay of applying this property to element.

Comment: I think you will have to look into javascript libraries, that are able to wait for animations to complete and then apply a property change. Which one you choose is entirely up to you of course.

Comment: I would like to to it completely in CSS so JS is not the way I want to go.

Comment: So you want to give position static to orange container after animation ? And what do u gain from that ?

Comment: I've made a better example what is the problem here. I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please add code into the question, not just a codepen link. Why? If that link dies, so does this question.

Comment: Now should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking about changing position why not changing how the animation works. You may try the use of **scale** and adjust `transform-origin` to decide how the image should move (and also optimize your markup)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.container img:nth-child(even) {
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.container img:nth-child(2n+5) {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.container img:nth-child(2n+6) {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.container img:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/150/150/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6BwaeUjaDnM/TZSPiw4YeoI/AAAAAAAAAf4/YlxYyxxu6nE/s400/2.jpg">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6BwaeUjaDnM/TZSPiw4YeoI/AAAAAAAAAf4/YlxYyxxu6nE/s400/2.jpg">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/pqwPJPgR6qCB2/giphy.gif">
  <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/f0f4/i/2017/182/c/6/pvz_heroes_random_colored_doodle_of_nc_by_crystilialance-dbeqssx.png">
</div>
```

Comment: It looks smooth, but the direction of growing the bottom and right images is wrong unfortunately. That's why I believe absolute is a thing to use here.

Comment: @J33nn it's not wrong :) as i said in my answer you have to change transform origin, i simply put the same to all of them ... but you can use your previous selectord (nth-of-type, etc) to change transform origin of each image like you want. The can grow in any direction you want (top, right, left, bottom, center, top-left, bottom-right, etc etc)

Comment: this is so cool! Thank you! Didn't see your suggestion on the transform-origin adjustments. Just went straight to the solution ;) my mistake.